# Cleaning up a List of HTML Data to Render Usable Information

Tags: programming, html, text

I am using Mathematica to scrape information from webpages. To get file information, I am gathering plain text that is enclosed by `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags. I have made a list, of which each element is the entire data. I want to somehow scrape the plaintext readable element out of this.

By way of example, here are two elements from my list:

```
   "<tr>
         <td class=\"td_data\" valign=\"top\">1.</td>
         <td class=\"td_data\" valign=\"top\">1841-1869 (Province of \
    Canada), number 195, 21 June 1845, page 15</a></td>
    <td class=\"td_data\" valign=\"top\"><a \
    href=\"093/001060-119.01-e.php?image_id_nbr=2592&document_id_nbr=1857&\
    f=g&PHPSESSID=kq2k6i3u6qodbjdp1ardk0ca96\">GIF</a> | <a \
    href=\"093/001060-119.01-e.php?image_id_nbr=2592&document_id_nbr=1857&\
    f=p&PHPSESSID=kq2k6i3u6qodbjdp1ardk0ca96\">PDF</a></td>
    </tr>", "<tr>
         <td class=\"td_data\" valign=\"top\">2.</td>
         <td class=\"td_data\" valign=\"top\">1841-1869 (Province of \
    Canada), number 402, Extra, 16 May 1849, page 4</a></td>
    <td class=\"td_data\" valign=\"top\"><a \
    href=\"093/001060-119.01-e.php?image_id_nbr=6979&document_id_nbr=2061&\
    f=g&PHPSESSID=kq2k6i3u6qodbjdp1ardk0ca96\">GIF</a> | <a \
    href=\"093/001060-119.01-e.php?image_id_nbr=6979&document_id_nbr=2061&\
    f=p&PHPSESSID=kq2k6i3u6qodbjdp1ardk0ca96\">PDF</a></td>
    </tr>"
```

I've been playing around with `Shorten[]` and `StringCases[]` to try to find a way, but would there be a way to quickly map a function on this list that would result in the following:

```
"1841-1869 (Province of Canada), number 195, 21 June 1845, page 15",
"1841-1869 (Province of Canada), number 402, Extra, 16 May 1849, page 4."
```

The actual text changes, i.e. it doesn't always say 1841-1869 etc., but the general format of the `<tr>` portion remains consistent. I don't mind if the GIF | PDF part remains either. Would there be a quick way to just render the actually visible part of the HTML file in this list?

---

If somebody wants to reproduce the list I am using, here is my code (I include this only to make things simpler, but this is probably more of a theoretical question):

```
baseurl = 
  "http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/databases/canada-gazette/001060-\
110.01-e.php?q1=youth&q3=&interval=199&sk=";
pagelist = 
  Import[baseurl <> ToString[#], "Source"] & /@ Range[1, 1889, 199];
pagetext = Apply[StringJoin, pagelist];
trlist = StringCases[pagetext, Shortest["<tr>" ~~ ___ ~~ "</tr>"]];
```

Comment: Have you tried importing the html file as "Data"? It might be easier to extract your data from that.

Comment: HTML is hell of a complicated file format (Example: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"><><title//<p ltr<span></span</p></>` is a valid document), can't you get your hands on some XML version of the page? (I didn't even consider what horrible code the average page has, catchword quirks mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the two strings in your first example, this seems to work

```
ImportString[string, "HTML"]
```

For the `baseurl` as in the original post, `Import[baseUrl, "Data"]` gives something like

```
data = Import[baseUrl, "Data"]
data[[2, ;; 4]]

{{"Item", "View Options"}, {
  1., "1841-1869 (Province of Canada), number 195, 21 June 1845, page \
15", "GIF | PDF"}, {
  2., "1841-1869 (Province of Canada), number 402, Extra, 16 May \
1849, page 4", "GIF | PDF"}, {
  3., "1841-1869 (Province of Canada), number 405, 26 May 1849, page \
15", "GIF | PDF"}}
```

so it looks like `data[[2, ;; ,2]]` gives you the list you're after.

Comment: Not quite. It produces extra pieces.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin do you mean the indices and the "GIF | PDF" at the beginning and end? I guess importing as "Table" as in you solution gets rid of those, but it's probably easier to just import the file as "Data" in the first place in this case.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. When I was posting a comment, only the first part of your answer was available. Using "Data" is a good alternative, I agree.

Comment: Great, thank you. Let me play with this as soon as my internet connection works!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how robust this is, but this function seems to do what you want:

```
ImportString[
    ExportString[Delete[ImportString[#, "Table"], {{2}, {-2}}], "Table"], 
    "HTML"
] &
```

Comment: Great, thank you. For some reason, my internet connection is having trouble with Mathematica so it may take me a bit of time to verify this!

Comment: @Ian No problem, was happy to help.