# Extract information from HTML using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css

**TL;DR** Is there any way that we can parse HTML using CSS selectors in *Mathematica*, the way it is done in for example jQuery?

---

Extracting information from websites, i.e. [web-scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), in *Mathematica* can be time-consuming. The traditional techniques described in

- [Extract information from HTML using Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809812/extract-information-from-html-using-mathematica).

are simply not enough for most serious web-scraping tasks. Since the most common technique is to import HTML as symbolic XML and then parse the XML with `Cases` another user had the idea to abstract this method into a package that would turn CSS rules into patterns that can parse symbolic XML:

- [CSS Selectors for Symbolic XML](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49052/css-selectors-for-symbolic-xml)

Although the effort is praiseworthy there are a couple of drawbacks with his solution, primarily because it is only a proof-of-concept. Unfortunately it would take an unreasonable amount of time to build a solution based on this start that is even close to as good as what is already out there for other langauges, such as [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) or [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

**Is there any way we can get comparable functionality in *Mathematica*?**

The questions on this site alone show that there is a demand for a solution to this problem. A solution would make it possible to provide elegant answers to *at least* the following questions:

- [Fetching data from HTML source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/fetching-data-from-html-source)
- [How to scrape the headlines from New York Times and Wall Street Journal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/how-to-scrape-the-headlines-from-new-york-times-and-wall-street-journal?lq=1)
- [Automating sequential import of data from web](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/automating-sequential-import-of-data-from-web?lq=1)
- [Cleaning up a List of HTML Data to Render Usable Information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/cleaning-up-a-list-of-html-data-to-render-usable-information)
- [How to get an elements of given class that generated by javascripts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71610/how-to-get-an-elements-of-given-class-that-generated-by-javascripts/71614#71614)
- [Regular Expression - for html objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67246/regular-expression-for-html-objects/67248#67248)

There is also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25946/extracting-text-from-nested-html-lists-ul-li) question which demonstrates [Leonid Shifrin's HTML parser](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jMICGBQ1EEw). It could also have been avoided by starting from a jQuery-like HTML parser.

Comment: node.js is an option.  Not exactly small overhead, but it is cross operating system and I believe might be faster then most java implementations.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js

Comment: I actually went some way to building a XPATH engine in pure Mathematica using XMLElements. I just found the query semantics somewhat hard to understand at first pass. Maybe I would have been more successful with a CSS selector engine. I don't rule out that we would do this in the future.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Warning

This answer pertains to the original release of jsoupLink. The interface changed completely in a later version. Please see the [Github page](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) for the current interface.

=================================

As much as I would like to see a solution to this problem written in *Mathematica*, this is very unlikely given the scope of the problem. I would like to share a way to solve this using JLink, in the hope that it may help someone.

JLink, for those who don't know, is a package that comes with *Mathematica*. It allows you to execute Java code from within *Mathematica*. This means you can use any Java library out there to solve your problems without leaving the notebook interface. For this particular problem I will use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org), which is a parser just like the ones mentioned in the question.

## Downloading and installing the package

You can download the latest version as a zip file from [here](https://github.com/CEkdhl/jSoupLink/releases/tag/0.1).

It is important that the files are kept in the correct folder, otherwise *Mathematica* will not be able to locate the Java files. Therefore, to install the package start by evaluating

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

in *Mathematica* and unzip the zip file you downloaded into this folder. Then use `` Needs["`jSoupLink`"] `` to load the package.

## Usage

The package contains three functions: `ParseHTML`, `ParseHTMLString` and `ParseHTMLFragment`. Some information about these is contained in their usage messages, which, if you have loaded the package, you can view using for example

```
?jSoupLink`ParseHTML
```

Typically you will use `ParseHTML` to download HTML source code from a website and then select a few elements. From these elements you will then extract some data. The general syntax is like this:

```
jSoupLink`ParseHTML[
website address,
CSS selector,
data elements to extract
]
```

`website address` is any URL, for example `http://mathematica.stackexchange.com`. `CSS selector` is basically any valid CSS3 selector. There is a list of CSS3 selector in jSoup's [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). `Data elements to extract` can be almost anything contained by the elements that you've selected. Most commonly you'll want to extract *attributes* such as `src` if you've selected `img` elements or `href` if you've selected links (`a` elements). There are a few keywords that aren't attributes such as `text` to select the text contained by a selected element (some text in `<p>some text</p>`) or `html` to select the HTML contained by a selected element. You can glean the complete list from the package source code, and look them up in jSoup's documentation if you're not sure what they are.

## Examples

**Selecting images from Wikipedia**

```
urls = jSoupLink`ParseHTML[
   "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden", (* URL *)
   "table.infobox img", (* CSS selector *)
   "src" (* Attribute to retrieve *)
   ];
Partition[Import /@ urls, 2] // Grid
```

[image: Example images from Wikipedia]

**Select headlines (both text and URL) from NYT**

```
headlines = Rest@jSoupLink`ParseHTML[
    "http://www.nytimes.com/pages/politics/index.html",
    "h2 a, h3 a",
    {"text", "href"}
    ];
Take[headlines, 5] // TableForm
```

[image: NYT headlines]

**Build a database with information about Swedish municipalities, using data on Wikipedia**

```
headers = jSoupLink`ParseHTML[
   "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_of_Sweden",
   "table.wikitable.sortable th",
   "text"
   ];
headers = StringReplace[#, "(" ~~ __ ~~ ")" -> ""] & /@ headers; (* Remove units *)
headers = StringReplace[#, WordBoundary ~~ x_ :> ToUpperCase[x]] & /@ headers; (* Capitalize *)
headers = StringReplace[#, " " -> ""] & /@ headers;(* Remove spaces *)

municipalities = jSoupLink`ParseHTML[
   "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_of_Sweden",
   "table.wikitable.sortable td",
   "text"
   ];
municipalities = Partition[municipalities, 9];

ds = Dataset@Composition[
     Map[AssociationThread],
     Map[(headers -> #) &]
     ][municipalities];
```

Now if you want to select all municipalities that belong to the county Västra Götaland you just have to type

```
ds[Select[#County == "Västra Götaland County" &], "Municipality"] // Normal
```

> `{"Ale Municipality", "Alingsås Municipality", "Bengtsfors \
>   Municipality", "Bollebygd Municipality", ...`

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, I changed it.

Comment: It gives an error "A Java exception occurred: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \
org.jsoup.Jsoup" when loading the module

Comment: @Prastt My instructions for how to load the package were not very good, please look at the new instructions in this post.

Comment: @C.E. Hi can you check that this works on v12? It's giving me A Java exception occurred: MathLinkException: 49: Unable to convert from MathLink encoding to requested character encoding.

Comment: When running the sweden example

Comment: I got it working, but the installation instructions didn't work for me.

Comment: @C.E. How would you extract elements with jSoupLink? For example, the 10 random urls from here: `Import["https://www.randomlists.com/websites?dup=false&qty=10", "String"]`

Comment: @user5601 This answer showcases an old version of jsoupLink. Have a look at the [Github page](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) for the latest version of the interface. Typically, you would start with `element["Select", "<css selector here>"]` to select elements. Then you would loop over those elements and extract the property that you're interested in. `element["Attribute", "href"]` for example. To select random ones, you can first select all and then use `RandomChoice` to select a subset.

Comment: It's a wonderful library that would help even more users if it could be located [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository) or [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/). Thank you very much for your development work

Comment: @yode Thank you. I don't have Mathematica installed on my current computer, unfortunately, and that makes it difficult to maintain this package. I agree with you that it would be good to get this package into the package repository, but I have no immediate plans to do so because of this.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a simple quick fix solution.

1. Download http://nodejs.org/
2. run `npm install jquery`
3. Example http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=E2t9hSYu

Code

```
(function () {    
  var env = require('jsdom').env,
      // first argument can be html string, filename, or url
      html = '<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><p class="hello">Heya Big World!</body></html>';

  env(html, function (errors, window) {
    console.log(errors);

    var $ = require('jquery')(window);
    console.log($('.hello').text());
  });
}());
```

Then you can call the script using something like

```
Import["!node script.js", "Text"]
```

The data should be outputted to the console.  There is a slight bug listed here on Windows

[Run Command Not Executing Node](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99564/run-command-not-executing-node)

Comment: I think the question was about how to access the functionality from Mathematica and how to get back the results to Mathematica again.

Comment: Yes, what Szabolcs said; I often use jQuery to quickly extract some piece of information from HTML, but here I'm looking for ways to integrate jQuery style selectors seamlessly with Mathematica.

Comment: @Pickett Your answer is very well done compared to mine.  If you use [Watch File Directory](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61242/watch-file-in-directory-net) and `fs.writeFile(filename, data[, options], callback)` it should be seamless with a temporary file.  I am not familiar enough with the C hooks.

Comment: @William Can you please update your wonderful answer's installation steps? I follow them but get this at the Needs step: Get::noopen: Cannot open Global`jSoupLink`.

Comment: @William Actually that's not true, the Needs works... but when I call jSoupLink`ParseHTML in v12 on macos 10.15.2 I get this: Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: MathLinkException: 49: Unable to convert from MathLink encoding to requested character encoding.

Comment: @user5601 it's JavaScript not Java.  I will need to reinstall Mathematica to test this.

Comment: @William Sorry I mean to reply to the other answer

Comment: @user5601 I only got his answer to work once but it is a better answer.