# How can I import a table from a Wikipedia page?

Tags: import, wikipedia, version-10.1

I'm trying to import [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon) from a wikipedia page containing the list of lunar missions into a Mathematica as an `Association`. Here, I'm trying to use the new `WikipediaData` function, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
WikipediaData["PageID" -> "656253283", "ArticleWikicode"]
```

Comment: When I use your code, it doesn't work but `WikipediaData["List of missions to the Moon", "ArticleWikicode"]` works fine.

Comment: Oh `PageID` is wrong, the correct one is `38293476`.

Comment: You can alwars just use `Import` : `Import["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon", 
{"HTML", "Source"}]`   . ( `WikipediaData` doesn't work for me either by the way  )

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71914/extract-information-from-html-using-css-selectors) package could be used. The third example in that post is actually a table on Wikipedia.

Comment: The function you are using is not going to work because that's not the PageID of the article you are trying to import. The correct one is 38293476, so, WikipediaData["PageID" -> "38293476", "ArticleWikicode"] works fine. But as Mahdi said, you can also use the actual title as in WikipediaData["List of missions to the Moon", "ArticleWikicode"]

Answer (score 6):

my stab at it..

```
 source = Import[
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon",
            {"HTML", "Source"}];
 tstart = StringPosition[source, 
        "<table class=\"wikitable sortable\"" ][[1, 1]];
 tend = Select[ 
          StringPosition[source, "</table>"] , #[[1]] > tstart & ][[1, 2]];
 tabledata = 
       ImportString[
          StringTake[ source , {tstart, tend} ], {"html", "Data"}];
 Grid@tabledata
```

If there are more elegant ways of parsing html I'd like to see..

By the way `WikipediaData` gives me these sorts of errors no matter what I try:

> " ServiceObject::noget: The parameter Wikicode is not available for the service Wikipedia. >> "

Answer (score 5):

As george2079 said, you can use `Import`:

```
text = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon", "Data"];
```

and then naively because table has 7 columns:

```
table = Cases[text, {_, _, _,_, _, _, _}, ∞];
```

But you need to do some clean-up afterwards!