# Cannot access Mathematica data repository: "Removed Dataset"

Tags: curated-data

I want to use Mathematica's data repository, specifically their data on US State income. However, when I try to access the dataset:

```
ResourceData["US State Income"]
```

> ```
> Removed["Dataset"][{<|"State" -> Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Alabama", "UnitedStates"}], ...
> ```

I figured the dataset was removed from Mathematica's repository despite still being on their website, but I looked it up using ResourceSearch, and it still exists. Am I doing something wrong? Am I better off importing the data from elsewhere?

Comment: I see the same error on MMA 11.2. Alternatively, you might try importing the data from e.g. Wikipedia, which gets it from the US Census Bureau, so you have an attribution for the data as well. It will require some hand cleanup though. See e.g. [How can I import a table from a Wikipedia page?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82735/27951). There is also the builtin [`WikipediaData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WikipediaData.html), but it doesn't seem to go much further than `Import`, at least in my hands.