# Frequency of punctuation characters used in Mathematica languages

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, punctuation

I would like to determine the computer language character frequency in Mathematica code. I want to remap my keyboard to the most used character such as [], {}, -, +.

There are the frequency of punctuation characters reported for many progamming languages: C, C++, Java...

Could we report our Mathematica code to dertermine the frequency? So what is the most frequent character in Mathematica?

***ALL LANGUAGES***
[image]

Source: http://xahlee.info/comp/computer_language_char_distribution.html

Comment: I guess that strongly depends on your programming style (i.e. `f[x]` vs. `f@x` vs `x // f` ,or the improbable `x~f~Sequence[ ]`,  `{a, b}` vs. `List[a, b]`etc). So you first need **your** codebase

Comment: Also, numbers aren't usually considered "punctuation" or "special" characters!

Comment: The documentation center might prove a useful mine for WL code.

Comment: @belisarius I *think* I recall that in certain golf-oriented languages numbers are used as operators.

Comment: I think this question verges on *"**primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*  Unless someone can come up with an authoritative reference I will probably convert this to a community wiki as a compromise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like belisarius said in a comment, it's going to be a lot more accurate if you check the frequency on your own codebase. This is how to check the frequency of special characters in the 100 most popular answers on this site.

```
Needs["jSoupLink`"] (* Package: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71914/extract-information-from-html-using-css-selectors *)
url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&site=mathematica&filter=!1zSk*x-JSjj*nMuua98Vm";
data = Import[url, "JSON"];
data = "body" /. ("items" /. data);
answers = ParseHTMLFragment[#, "code", {"text"}] & /@ data;
counts = Tally@Characters[StringJoin @@ Flatten@answers];
counts = Reverse@SortBy[counts, Last];
    notSpecial = Join[
   CharacterRange["A", "Z"],
   CharacterRange["a", "z"],
   CharacterRange["0", "9"],
   {" "}
   ];
DeleteCases[counts, {Alternatives @@ notSpecial, _}] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If any user here wants to check their own character frequency, you can generate a URL that collects your answers by providing your user ID like this:

```
url[id_] := "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/" <> ToString@id <> "/answers?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=mathematica&filter=!4)7xaKyZCTSLfUVAL";
data = Import[url[yourUserId], "JSON"];
```

Comment: Cool, the top-100 posts don't have unmatched brackets! However, the number of double quotes is odd, which is odd (but not impossible).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The bracket matching fails in my codebase :)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Escaped quote perhaps?:  `"\""`

Comment: At first, I wondered why `>` was more frequent than `<`, until I remembered that `->` gets a lot of use here. On another note, I see that `~` is not too frequent; how many are willing to bet that a select few people are the reason for `~` to show up anyway? ;)

Comment: A select few wizards, you mean?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I checked the top 100 answers for each of the top 5 users and in those answers they used tilde 52 (Mr. W.), 0, 4, 3 and 28 (L.S.) times respectively. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
(* select your codebase files *)
SetDirectory[$InstallationDirectory];
fns = FileNames["*.nb", {"*"}, Infinity][[1 ;; 10]]
(* Read files and tally the chars *)
pp = SortBy[Tally@Flatten@(Characters[Import[#, "Text"]] & /@ fns), -#[[2]] &]
(* discard the letters & digits *)
pp1 = Select[pp, ! StringMatchQ[#[[1]], WordCharacter] &]
(* Plot *)
BarChart[pp1[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> pp1[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: the first two are "space" and "newline"

Comment: is that representative code?  Odd for `& , #` to be low and `?` so high..

Comment: @george2079 added the directory name :)

Comment: I see, this is importing the entire low level notebook. Properly you need to just include the text of input cells..

Comment: @george Good point!  belisarius, why not look at `.m` files instead?

Comment: Ashamed and pondering about to do :)

Comment: You should let it run for *all* `.m` files too; it only takes a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was thinking about how to use the nb files ...

Comment: If you don't post the `.m` data I will; what do you prefer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard be my guest. Still trying to figure out if the nb files are usable for this

Answer (score 3):

Applying belisarius's code to look at all included package files with the modification of:

```
fns = FileNames["*.m", {"*"}, Infinity];
```

I get:

[image]

Not much love for [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)-based functions it seems.

Comment: If I had to guess (just spitballing off of your note about `Slot`), it's that these files are generally source files like [documentedContexts.m[(https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151967/38205) which are lists of properties, file paths, etc. Plus some framework stuff, which is chaining small functions. Trying `$UserBasePacletsDirectory` gives very different, probably more representative, results.

Answer (score 2):

@belisarius is right to point out that the frequency strongly depends on the programming style. The answer reported above are mostly applied for .m file (package) file, where there are many comments `(* *)`, many strings `""`, such as in this code.

```
(* Mathematica Package *)
(* Created by the Wolfram Workbench 11-Jan-2010 *)    
(*
  TODO
    Way to pass down options with GenerateCode
    Support for unknown expressions passed into CForm
*)    
BeginPackage["SymbolicC`"]    
ToCCodeString::usage = "ToCCodeString[ symbolicC] generates a string of C code from a symbolic C expression."
```

That's why, the string `"` and `*` is really frequent in packages. But I want to check the character frequency in normal Mathematica example, not in packages, such as demonstrations, or fast-code example. This is the results from many featured demonstrations in Wolfram Demonstration project.

***ALL LANGUAGES***
[image]

Source: http://xahlee.info/comp/computer_language_char_distribution.html

***MATHEMATICA***
[image]

**Discussions:**

The `,` and `[`, `]` is the most frequent character. Due to the function, 
argument style `[argu1, argu2, argu3]`

`0, 1, 2` is mainly used in `Manipulate[...,{x,0,n}]`. In application demonstrations, number is very frequent.

`{}` is really important for list, and in `Manipulate[expr,{u,umin,umax}]`

The quote `"` are mainly used for interface such as `Row`, `Style`, `Text`, `Labels`, `Options`, `Appearances` ...

`=` is important (`Set`)

`/` and `.` are used in `ReplaceAll` `/.`

`;` is less frequent

`>` is more frequent than `<`, used in `:>`, `->`

`_` and `:` are mainly used for function declaration but less frequent. In daily Mathematica use, no need to delaire new function :)

Surprisingly, `@`, `&`, `#` are really important in functional programming, but less frequent in demonstrations.

**Remap keyboard**
Finally, I will remap my keyboard for the `[],{}` using with my thumb, index finger in Mathematica because these are the most used characters. For numbers, I will use the numeric keyboard because pressing `0` with right pinky finger is painful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to extend belisarius's method to compare two code bases, by looking at the percent-wise distribution of punctuation characters:

```
codeBaseCounts[files_] :=

 KeySelect[Not@*StringMatchQ[WhitespaceCharacter | WordCharacter]]@
    AssociationThread[
     Map[FromCharacterCode]@Keys[#],
     Values[#]/Total[Values[#]]
     ] &@SortBy[
   Counts@Flatten@(ToCharacterCode@Import[#, "Text"] & /@ files), -# &]

codeBaseCountsPlot[assoc_, ops___?OptionQ] :=

 BarChart[Values@assoc, ops, ChartLabels -> Keys@assoc]

codingStyleCompare[files1_List, files2_List] :=

 With[{base1 = codeBaseCounts[files1], base2 = codeBaseCounts[files2]},
  Grid[{
    {
     codeBaseCountsPlot[
      Association@
       KeyValueMap[
        # -> #2 - base2[#] &,
        base1
        ],
      ImageSize -> 500
      ],
     SpanFromLeft
     },
    {
     codeBaseCountsPlot[base1, ImageSize -> 250],
     codeBaseCountsPlot[base2, ImageSize -> 250]
     }
    },
   ItemSize -> Full
   ]
  ]
```

This lets up do things like this:

```
codingStyleCompare[
 FileNames["*.m", $UserBasePacletsDirectory, Infinity],
 FileNames["*.m", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]
 ]
```

[image: compare]

which shows, I think, that the `$UserBasePacletsDirectory` contains more code, as the number of square-brackets increases as a percentage, representing more calls. It also contains many more string characters, though, which is interesting. Probably from the PacletInfo.m files.