# strse error in string operation

Tags: string-manipulation

When I using [jSoupLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71915/4742), I found strange behaviour

First, I load `jSoupLink` and define `linkList`

```
<< jSoupLink`
linkList = \
{"https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2015/\
kajita-facts.html", 
   "https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2015/\
mcdonald-facts.html", 
   "https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2014/\
akasaki-facts.html"};
```

Now the below `Map` works fine

```
Map[
 StringSplit[
   ParseHTML[#, ".laureate_info_wrapper p", "text"], {",", 
    ":"}] &, linkList]
```

However `ParallelMap` gives strse error

```
ParallelMap[
 StringSplit[
   ParseHTML[#, ".laureate_info_wrapper p", "text"], {",", 
    ":"}] &, linkList]
```

will gives errors

> StringSplit::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1
>   in
>   StringSplit[jSoupLink`ParseHTML[https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2015/kajita-facts.html,.laureate_info_wrapper
>   p,text],{,,:}].

It seems not the problem of `ParseHTML`, because

```
ParallelMap[
 ParseHTML[#, ".laureate_info_wrapper p", "text"]&, linkList]
```

has no problem.

What is wrong?

Comment: You probably need to load the definitions for jSoupLink into the parallel kernels (e.g. by `DistributeDefinitions` or by loading them explicitly).

Comment: @WReach Hi, WReach. I updated my post. I think it is not the problem of jSoupLink